# Update two elements with two jquery .post responses

Tags: jquery, django

There are two lists on the page: 'To buy' and 'Recently bought'. Each list can contain items. After clicking on an item the item is supposed to be removed from the original list and inserted into the other list.
It works for some items but sometimes I have to click twice to move the item. I assume there is something wrong with my *makeactive* and *makeinactive* functions but what and how would you recommend fixing it?

**home.html**

```
<h3>To buy:</h3>
{% csrf_token %}
<ul id="only_active">
{% for item in active %}
    <li id='{{ item.id }}' class="active">{{ item.name }}, id: {{ item.id }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<h3>Recently bought:</h3>
<ul id='recently_bought'>
{% for item in inactive %}
    <li id='{{ item.id }}' class="inactive">{{ item.name }}, id: {{ item.id }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**js**

```
function makeinactive(){
    // changes item from active to inactive (item.active=True into False)
    id = this.id;
    console.log(id);
    var data = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()};
    URL =  id + '/switch/'
    $.post(URL, data, function(response){
        $('#recently_bought').html(response);
    });

    // updates the list of active items
    URL =  '/only_active/'
    $.post(URL, data, function(response){
        $('#only_active').html(response);
    });
}

function makeactive(){
    // changes item from inactive to active (item.active=False into True)
    id = this.id;
    console.log(id);
    var data = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()};
    URL =  id + '/switch2/'
    $.post(URL, data, function(response){
        $('#only_active').html(response);
    });

    // updates the list of recently bought items
    URL =  '/only_inactive/'
    $.post(URL, data, function(response){
        $('#recently_bought').html(response);
    });
}

$(document).on('click', '.active',  makeinactive);
$(document).on('click', '.inactive',  makeactive);
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/switch/$', views.switch, name='switch'),
    url(r'^only_active/$', views.only_active, name='only_active'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/switch2/$', views.switch2, name='switch2'),
    url(r'^only_inactive/$', views.only_inactive, name='only_inactive'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    active = Item.objects.filter(active=True)
    inactive = Item.objects.filter(active=False)
    context = {'active': active, 'inactive': inactive}
    return render(request, 'tobuy/home.html', context)

def switch(request, pk=None):
    item = Item.objects.get(pk=pk)
    item.active = False
    item.save()
    inactive = Item.objects.filter(active=False)
    return render(request, 'tobuy/only_inactive.html', {'inactive': inactive})

def only_active(request):
    active = Item.objects.filter(active=True)
    return render(request, 'tobuy/only_active.html', {'active': active})

def switch2(request, pk=None):
    item = Item.objects.get(pk=pk)
    item.active = True
    item.save()
    active = Item.objects.filter(active=True)
    return render(request, 'tobuy/only_active.html', {'active': active})

def only_inactive(request):
    inactive = Item.objects.filter(active=False)
    return render(request, 'tobuy/only_inactive.html', {'inactive': inactive})
```

**only_inactive.html**

```
{% for item in inactive %}
    <li id='{{ item.id }}' class="inactive">{{ item.name }}, id: {{ item.id }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

**only_active.html**

```
{% for item in active %}
    <li id='{{ item.id }}' class="active">{{ item.name }}, id: {{ item.id }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code fix the issue. I'm not entirely sure but probably due to delays I introduced (setTimeout).
**myjs.js**

```
function fill_recently_bought(data, textStatus, jgXHR)
{
   $('#recently_bought').html(data);
}

function fill_active(data, textStatus, jgXHR)
{
   $('#only_active').html(data);
}

function makeinactive()
{
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow').delay(500).hide(500);

    // changes item from active to inactive (item.active=True into False)
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: this.id + '/switch/',
                data: {
                    'pk':  this.id,
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
                },
                success: fill_recently_bought,
                dataType: 'html'
            });

    // updates the list of active items

    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/only_active/',
                data: {
                    'pk':  this.id,
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
                },
                success: fill_active,
                dataType: 'html'
            });
    }, 1000);
}


function makeactive()
{
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow').delay(500).hide(500);

    // changes item from inactive to active (item.active=False into True)
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: this.id + '/switch2/',
                data: {
                    'pk':  this.id,
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
                },
                success: fill_active,
                dataType: 'html'
            });

    // updates the list of active items

    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/only_inactive/',
                data: {
                    'pk':  this.id,
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
                },
                success: fill_recently_bought,
                dataType: 'html'
            });
    }, 1000);
}


function show_lists() {
    $('#lists').toggleClass('hidden');
}

// function formsubmit() {
//     alert('submituje2');
// }

$(document).on('click', '.active',  makeinactive);
$(document).on('click', '.inactive',  makeactive);
$(document).on('click', '#select_list',  show_lists);
// $(document).on('submit', '#new_user_form',  formsubmit);
```